# Creating a controller later on in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I created these controllers in my app:
`rails generate controller pages index about`

Later I decided to create a new one (not sure if it is the right way) but I got a warning because `pages` already existed:

```
$ rails generate controller pages contact                                                                                                        
    conflict  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb                                                                                                                                                
Overwrite /home/action/workspace/myapp/app/controllers/pages_controller.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]                                                                                        
       force  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb                                                                                                                                                
       route  get 'pages/contact'                                                                                                                                                                
      invoke  erb                                                                                                                                                                                
       exist    app/views/pages                                                                                                                                                                  
      create    app/views/pages/contact.html.erb                                                                                                                                                 
      invoke  test_unit                                                                                                                                                                          
    conflict    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb                                                                                                                                        
  Overwrite /home/action/workspace/myapp/test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]                                                                                
       force    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb                                                                                                                                        
      invoke  helper                                                                                                                                                                             
   identical    app/helpers/pages_helper.rb                                                                                                                                                      
      invoke    test_unit                                                                                                                                                                        
   identical      test/helpers/pages_helper_test.rb                                                                                                                                              
      invoke  assets                                                                                                                                                                             
      invoke    coffee                                                                                                                                                                           
   identical      app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee                                                                                                                                         
      invoke    scss                                                                                                                                                                             
   identical      app/assets/stylesheets/pages.css.scss
```

After hitting enter everything works fine but in `pages_controller.rb` the new page `contact` wasn't added:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @notice = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

I'm new to rails and this is my question: Is it the right way to add new pages to controllers?

I can just type `def contact` to add it but probably there is another way. Adding one page manually is ok but if I have to add several it would be a nightmare. If it wasn't clear I'll try to re-phrase it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely replace the controller, it is cleaner to destroy it first:

```
 ~$ rails destroy controller pages
  remove  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  remove    app/views/pages
  invoke  test_unit
  remove    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  remove    app/helpers/pages_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  remove      test/helpers/pages_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  remove      app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  remove      app/assets/stylesheets/pages.css.scss

 ~$ rails generate controller pages contact
  create  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
   route  get 'pages/contact'
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/pages
  create    app/views/pages/contact.html.erb
  invoke  test_unit
  create    test/controllers/pages_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/pages_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/helpers/pages_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/pages.css.scss
```

Comment: Hi! I had in `pages_controller.rb` index and about. Later on I wanted to add contact. I guess that after creating the project if I want to add more pages I have to go to `pages_controller.rb` and do it manually. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, then have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218587/how-do-i-add-new-action-and-view-with-script-rails-generate). TL;DR: you do it by hand.